# Substitute web.xml variables at startup

Tags: java, filter, war, web.xml

I have a web.xml file that constains variables in context-param and init-param of filters. I want to replace this variable with values taken from a properties file at application's startup.

My web.xml is like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

<display-name>APP NAME</display-name>
<description>
    App description
</description>
<context-param>
    <param-name>my-param-name</param-name>
    <param-value>${my-param-name}</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>Authentication Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>my.app.Filter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>filter-var-name</param-name>
        <param-value>${filter-var-value}</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
...
</web-app>
```

And the web.properties

```
my-param-name=${PARAM_VALUE_TO_BE_SETTED_BY_TOOL}
filter-var-value=${FILTER_VALUE_TO_BE_SETTED_BY_TOOL}
```

Here is how the deployment works:

1) A deployment tool read a given properties file and replace variables with PROD or Dev values (values setted in that tool) and push the file to application module under a JBoss;

2) Start application's deployment on a JBoss. I want that web.xml variables be substituted by properties file values on startup.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the why you want to do that? If it's just "not messing with webapp web.xml" you should consider using context parameters for these values and configure them on deployment (in a separate context.xml for your context)

Comment: two thoughts on that: a) replace values directly in web.xml instead of inside properties file in step 1 or recode Filter and places you access context parameters to read properties values instead.

Comment: The first one is what I have now but not good because I must have one war file for PROD and DEV. I cannot implemnts the second suggestion because I can't recode all filters.

Comment: DEV and PROD will be running in different JBoss Instances, right? Most application servers allow for some kind of variable subsitution (tomcat: with system properties) in XML files. Maybe that's a viable option?

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26514663/environment-variables-in-jboss-datasource is helpful?

Comment: I have aleady seen this solution. But the staff that deploy application has a standard standalone.xml file that cannot contains any substitution value. I want to do something like that (replace web.xml's variables via a servlet listener): http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/

Answer (score 0):

We have created a wrapped filter that extends Servlet Filter to set values to web.xml filters variables. These values are taken from an external properties file for DEV and PROD envirnments.

Web.xml:

```
...
<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>my.package.WrappedFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>key</param-name>
        <param-value>wrappedCasFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>class</param-name>
        <param-value>org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
...
```

Properties file:

```
wrappedCasFilter.init.casServerLoginUrl = https://URL
```

I am sad that I cant't show you the WrappedFilter content.